# Shuffling array in Java using Random.nextInt two times

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle

Is an array of integers correctly shuffled when using Random.nextInt two times for interchanging two values?

Example code:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        nIndexOld = rand.nextInt(values.length);
        nIndexNew = rand.nextInt(values.length);

        nTempValue = values[nIndexOld];
        values[nIndexOld] = values[nIndexNew];
        values[nIndexNew] = nTempValue;
    }
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array

Answer (score 1):

No, your algorithm cannot give homogeneous distribution of possible permutations. See the explanation of the similar error in the section ["Implementation errors"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

> This can be seen from the fact that doing so yields n<sup>n</sup> distinct
>   possible sequences of swaps, whereas there are only n! possible
>   permutations of an n-element array...

Your case is a little different, but the same logic can be applied. On each iteration step you generate two randoms (`0...n-1`), so there are `n * n` possible array changes that can be applied. You do this `n` times. So, the total number of paths that you can go with equal probability is `(n * n)`<sup>`n`</sup>, but there are `n!` possible permutations.

For example, you have three elements. On each step there are `3 * 3 = 9` ways to change your current state. Doing that three times gives `9 * 9 * 9 = 729` possible ways to change initial array. It would be perfect to have equal number of all possible permutations in that set. However, there are `3! = 6` possible different final results. The number of generated permutations `729` is not divisible by `6`. So for sure some permutations have higher chance to be chosen.

For proper Java implementations of the modern version of the Fisher–Yates shuffle see for example [Random shuffling of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Better limiting nextInt to the size of the incoming array

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    nIndexOld = rand.nextInt(values.length);
    nIndexNew = rand.nextInt(values.length);

    nTempValue = values[nIndexOld];
    values[nIndexOld] = values[nIndexNew];
    values[nIndexNew] = nTempValue;
}
```

Comment: Sure, you're right, I corrected it in the question. But is it correct otherwise?

Comment: Such algorithm does not give equal probability for all permutations. Some results have higher chance to be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

If in your example

```
values.length = 40
```

Then yes the array is indeed shuffled properly.